# Basic questions on predict() using rpart model

Tags: r

I'm coming over from Weka and am trying to learn R's `predict()` function.

Suppose I would like to make predictions on a categorical variable, as shown below with the built-in kyphosis data set. I am using rpart, and I am calling `predict()` with the training data acting as the test data.

```
> library(rpart)
> head(kyphosis)
  Kyphosis Age Number Start
1   absent  71      3     5
2   absent 158      3    14
3  present 128      4     5
4   absent   2      5     1
5   absent   1      4    15
6   absent   1      2    16
> 
> kyphosisModel <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data=kyphosis)
> 
> kyphosisPredictions1 <- predict(kyphosisModel, kyphosis)
> head(kyphosisPredictions1)
     absent   present
1 0.4210526 0.5789474
2 0.8571429 0.1428571
3 0.4210526 0.5789474
4 0.4210526 0.5789474
5 1.0000000 0.0000000
6 1.0000000 0.0000000
> 
> kyphosisPredictions2 <- predict(kyphosisModel, kyphosis[,-1])
> head(kyphosisPredictions2)
     absent   present
1 0.4210526 0.5789474
2 0.8571429 0.1428571
3 0.4210526 0.5789474
4 0.4210526 0.5789474
5 1.0000000 0.0000000
6 1.0000000 0.0000000
```

So here are my specific questions:

1. When I call `predict()` with test data, I understand that the features (attribute columns) in the test data must match the features in the test data. **But do I need to remove the predicted label (the attribute column being predicted)?** In the example above, I created `kyphosisPredictions2` using a test data set that omitted the predicted column (column 1), which resulted in the same predictions as `kyphosisPredictions1`, which included the predicted column. This could have been a coincidence, so I would like to make sure. **Does the answer to this question (yes or no) apply regardless of the machine learning model being supplied to predict()?**
2. The predictions on the categorical column evidently give me a probability distribution over 'absent' and 'present'. Is there any way to return the single predicted level only, ie. either 'absent' or 'present' per row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `predict()` it won't matter whether you include the label or not for the test set, since the model will only use the variables that it was trained on. For your second question, just specify which column that you want. For example, if you wanted absent:

`kyphosisPredictions2 <- predict(kyphosisModel, kyphosis[,-1])[, 1]`

You could do it using the column name as well:

`kyphosisPredictions2 <- predict(kyphosisModel, kyphosis)[, "absent"]`

Comment: Thanks. But for the second question, what I want is a single prediction represented as the highest-probability level (or its string), not the probability values. For example, for a given test row, I am looking for the prediction result 'absent' (or its string) if Pr(absent) has the highest probability.

Comment: You can do that as well using apply (e.g. `apply(kyphosisPredictions2, 1, which.max)`, but how are you planning on using this. Do you just want the class prediction? You can do that by using the `type` argument in predict: `kyphosisPredictions2 <- predict(kyphosisModel, kyphosis, type = "class")`

Comment: Thanks for the 'type="class"'. Didn't know that was important.